# precision error in output

Tags: java, precision

```
double x = 9/2
//x == 4.0?
```

The output should be 4.5, but is 4.0
What would be the mistake I made?

Comment: `9/2` returns `4` (since you are dividing `int`s result is also `int`).

Comment: Some code would be helpful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`9/2  <-` without decimal you are specify this as a `int`

`9.0 / 2.0 <-` this is now `double` and you should able to get 4.5